# How do I format php string for Paypal checkout items

Tags: php

How can I style the output of Paypal check out items? I need to add line breaks and bold text.

I have tried with  the following: `<br>`, `\n` and  `\r\n` all just get printed out in html

tried example:

```
 $item = new Item();
        $item->setName( $songs[$i]['title'] . '\n' . " [" . $songs[$i]['plan'] ."]")
```

So what I have right now for the items list is

```
$item = new Item();
        $item->setName( $songs[$i]['title'] ." [" . $songs[$i]['plan'] ."]")
```

That outputs

"song name  [basic]" It prints on same line.

I need it to be on separate lines and bold. So

```
<br>
Song name
<br>
[basic]
<br>
```

Comment: Don't know about Paypal's API, but try `PHP_EOL` (or `"\n"`, with double quotes).

Comment: None of those worked. Still printing inline

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213040/paypal-item-name-description-on-separate-lines-using-forms might be related

Comment: Now I see why normal php wasn't working. Good find!